# gtkmm textview epands instead of scrolling

Tags: c++, scroll, gtkmm

I have a window that's set up with a grid attached to the window, a bunch of stuff in the grid and then a textview on the rightmost column occupying the entire column.

When I add text to the textview, instead of starting to scroll, the window just expands in order to accomodate the text. How can I get it to scroll instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the text view inside a `Gtk::ScrolledWindow` and put the scrolled window in the rightmost column of the grid instead.

Comment: Works, Thank you! :)